# Is this correct use of nor? (with "may not be able to")

Tags: word-usage, neither-nor

Is the use of "nor" here correct? "The XXX acknowledges that XXX may not be able to withhold a record (e.g., data, document, etc.) nor deny access to a record requested pursuant to the Act..." 
I think I'm getting tripped up by the "may not" part. I'm leaning more towards replacing nor with or.

Comment: I read a proper legal contract the other day, it didn't seem to actually be written in english, so i don't think it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not go fast **or** get good gas mileage, but ...